# Size Attribute is not showing on front end of WooCommerce site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website. Options for size attribute is not showing on the front end of my website although the size attribute and options are present on the back end. Check the product below.
http://nervesdeals.com/product/band-detail-mint-green-blouse/

I tried disabling my optimizations plugins but it didn't work. I got a solution which is to remove the size attribute and adding it again. this is working but it requires a lot of rework so I am want to know why this problem is occurring and is there a better solution than the current solution I have.

Comment: I see that you are using a premium theme, did you ask for support?

Comment: its a free version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because of the q-translate plugin. i removed all products and disabled the plugin and then uploaded a backup(before the installation of q-translate plugin) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery issue check screenshot http://prntscr.com/n9xeir so can you please fix all jQuery issue then size attribute will be work.

Comment: i don't think so because removing the size attribute and adding it again works

Comment: Options are showing for this product 
http://nervesdeals.com/product/back-zipped-detailed-embroidered-blue-dress/

Comment: Okay but currently I got page not found may be you removed product. this case any other plugin conflict with woocommerce